# When is NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum error thrown exactly in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsurlerrordomain

I wanted to know when NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum is thrown exactly in iOS.Read apple documentation regarding this error but it is not sufficient for understanding the scenario when this error is thrown.Is this error thrown as a result  of any server side issue or iOS issue?.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

From apple documentation it [says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrordatalengthexceedsmaximum?language=objc) :

> **NSURLErrorDataLengthExceedsMaximum** Returned when the length of the
>   resource data exceeds the maximum allowed.

I recommend using `POST` request instead of `GET` and send the data as **parameters** not in the URL